# Does utils::rtags() work for code in Rmarkdown files?

Tags: r, r-markdown, ctags

I am trying to using `utils::rtags()` to build indexes for R code.

This works fine for *.R files as such.

I have not been able to get it to work for code in Rmarkdown files (*.Rmd).

With the proper pattern argument, it finds the files fine, but seems to completely ignore the code they contain. An empty 'TAGS' file is created. For example:

```
utils::rtags(pattern='[.]Rmd$', ofile='TAGS', type='etags')
```

Am I expecting too much?

Comment: I am pretty sure `rtags` wouldn't understand Rmd syntax.  Maybe if you run the source through `knitr::purl` first it would be happy, but it would make references to the wrong file unless `knitr::purl` could be convinced to add `#line` directives.

Comment: Yeah `utils::rtags` uses the internal R parser to annotate code. R itself knows nothing about Rmarkdown syntax. All those features are provided by external packages. The R parser would be unable to know how to extract just code chunks from the document. It would only see a file with invalid R syntax.

Comment: In Univeral Ctags (https://ctags.io), I'm working on RMarkdown. If you are interested, see https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/pull/3309 .

Comment: Hello @masatakeyamato, that is interesting. Is it correct to believe rmarkdown support is still a work in progress in Universal CTAGS? FWIW, I normally use MS Windows as my OS. I see you provide Win32 builds on the CTAGS github repo. Are those pretty well supported?

Comment: @DaveBraze, yes, it is not merged yet. However, I will merge it in soon; there is no blocker. The win32 repo releases a binary package(?) daily.

Comment: @MasatakeYAMATO thanks again. I'll keep an eye on it. In the mean time, can you point me to any reference about how universal ctags project compares, in terms of goals and features, with other tagging utilities? Is there something like this that includes universal ctags? https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/wiki/Comparison-with-Similar-Tools

Comment: @DaveBraze, as you found, what I know is the opengrok's page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "No, `utils::rtags()` does not understand rmarkdown files."

But, https://ctags.io/ may (soon?) provide an alternative solution.

h/t @masatake-yamato (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6386727/masatake-yamato)

Comment: Now, the ctags provides RMarkdown parser. https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/commit/3bbeaff45d748874f566350ab065b5510e382c16